# Select Case With Conditions ( Classic ASP)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, select-case

```
<%
i=2 
  Select Case i
  Case 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10
    response.write("Grade A")
  Case 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20  
    response.write("Grade B")
  Case 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30
    response.write("Grade C")
  Case 31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
    response.write("Grade D")
  Case Else
    response.write("Invalid")
  End Select
  %>
```

how to replace 1,2,3.. with a smaller statement. I have tried putting 1 To 10 but it is showing error.

Appreciate any help , thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Some alternatives

```
grade = "Invalid"
Select Case True
    Case i < 1   
    Case i < 11 : grade = "Grade A"
    Case i < 21 : grade = "Grade B"
    Case i < 31 : grade = "Grade C"
    Case i < 41 : grade = "Grade D"
End Select
```

or

```
If i > 0 And i < 41 Then 
    grade = "Grade " + Chr(Asc("A") + (i-1)\10)
Else 
    grade = "Invalid"
End If
```

or

```
If i > 0 And i < 41 Then 
    grade = Array("Grade A", "Grade B", "Grade C", "Grade D")((i-1)\10)
Else 
    grade = "Invalid"
End If
```

***edited*** to correct the error pointed by Ekkehard.Horner

Comment: 32 is a counter example for alt. 2.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, of course, you are right. I should not post while being called for dinner. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

As your specs boil down to a regular/**computable** mapping, `Select Case` **or** `If .. ElseIf` - i.e. cherry picking - are the wrong tools anyway:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i

For i = -1 to 42
    If 1 > i Or 40 < i Then
       WScript.Echo i, "invalid"
    Else
       WScript.Echo i, Chr(65 + ((i - 1) \ 10))
    End If
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 43214055.vbs
-1 invalid
0 invalid
1 A
2 A
3 A
4 A
5 A
6 A
7 A
8 A
9 A
10 A
11 B
12 B
13 B
14 B
15 B
16 B
17 B
18 B
19 B
20 B
21 C
22 C
23 C
24 C
25 C
26 C
27 C
28 C
29 C
30 C
31 D
32 D
33 D
34 D
35 D
36 D
37 D
38 D
39 D
40 D
41 invalid
42 invalid
```

Answer (score -2):

You're using VBScript in your page.  It has no support of ranges in a `Select Case` statement.  You may be better off using `If/ElseIf` statements.

```
<%
    i=2
    If i > 0 And i <= 10 Then
        Response.Write("Grade A")
    ElseIf i > 10 And i <= 20 Then
        Response.Write("Grade B")
    ElseIf i > 20 And i <=30 Then
        Response.Write("Grade C")
    ElseIf i > 30 And i <= 40 Then
        Response.Write("Grade D")
    Else
        Response.Write("Invalid")
    End If
%>
```